# Power BI - Como definir um determinado valor quando a célula da matriz não contem valor

Tags: matriz, powerbi

construí uma matriz no Power bi e tenho algumas células cujo valor está vazia.
Isso ocorre pois a disciplina que está relacionada ao curso em coluna, realmente não possuí valor, pois para alguns cursos não tem aquela determina disciplina.

Já tentei montar alguns medidas para validar o campo "Media da Turma", utilizei a validação com IF = blank() ou até mesmo o Coalesce.
Nenhuma das medidas deram certo.

Como eu posso contornar esse problema.

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lt1De.jpg)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Utilize o `ISBLANK(validacao)`